# How to test an Heroku Buildpack without committing and pushing to heroku server each time

Tags: php, symfony, heroku

I am working on a heroku buildpack that will allow the deployment of symfony2 PHP applications to Heroku.
Each time I do a modification in the buildpack I follow the folowing procedure to test it:

```
echo 1 >> dummy
git add .
git commit -m "heroku"
git push heroku master
```

The first line (`echo 1 >> dummy`) is just to guarantee that is there something to commit. Otherwise when pushing to heroku the deployment with my buildpack would not be triggered.

I suspect there exists an easier and may be more elegant way of testing an heroku buildpack.

I would like to know if heroku exposes a way to test buildpacks or is there a way to test it without committing and pushing each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`heroku push`](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-push), with that, you can specify a local buildpack:

```
$ heroku push -b ~/mybuildpack
```

There's also [Mason](https://github.com/ddollar/mason), but I don't know much about that.